# AttributeError in callback function

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, attributeerror

I'm really sorry to bother you with an AttributeError, but I just can't figure out what's wrong with my code though I worked through many solved question regarding AttributeErrors.

This is my code:

```
class Base:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.window.set_size_request(500,500*9/16)
        self.window.set_title("pattern_executer")

        self.button1 = gtk.Button(" E x i t ")
        self.button1.connect("clicked",self.close)

        self.button2 = gtk.Button("Plot")
        self.button2.connect("clicked",self.plot)

        self.button3 = gtk.Button("Search")
        self.button3.connect("clicked",self.search)

        self.entry1 = gtk.Entry()
        self.entry1.connect("changed",self.dir_ch)
        self.entry1.set_text("dir1")

        self.entry2 = gtk.Entry()
        self.entry2.connect("changed",self.dir_ch)
        self.entry2.set_text("name")

        self.entry3 = gtk.Entry()
        self.entry3.connect("changed",self.dir_ch)
        self.entry3.set_text("dir2")

        #self.label1 = gtk.Label("FUNCTIONS")

        fixed1 = gtk.Fixed()
        fixed1.put(self.button1,10,250)
        fixed1.put(self.button2,10,60)
        fixed1.put(self.button3,10,30)
        fixed1.put(self.entry1,90,30)
        fixed1.put(self.entry2,90,60)
        fixed1.put(self.entry3,90,90)


        self.window.add(fixed1)
        self.window.show_all()
        self.window.connect("destroy",self.close)

    def run(self,widget):

        print "Run ... "


    def search(self,widget):
        box = (settings[1] - settings[3]/2,settings[2] - settings[4]/2,settings[1] + settings[3]/2,settings[2] + settings[4]/2)
        cut1 = im.crop(box)
        cut1.show()

    def cut(self):
        box = (settings[1] - settings[3]/2,settings[2] - settings[4]/2,settings[1] + settings[3]/2,settings[2] + settings[4]/2)
        cut1 = im.crop(box)
        return cut1

    def gpv(self): #get pixel value
        data = self.cut()
        data = list(data.getdata())
        data = np.array(data)
        data = data.reshape(settings[4],settings[3])   
        data = np.flipud(data)
        return data

    def plot(self,widget):        
        xlist = np.linspace(0,1.0,settings[3])
        ylist = np.linspace(0,1.0,settings[4])
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)

        fig = plt.figure()        
        fig = plt.contour(X, Y, self.gpv(),settings[0],colors = "k")
        fig = plt.contourf(X, Y, self.gpv(),settings[0])

        plt.show(fig)

    def dir_ch(self,widget):
        directories[0] = self.entry1.get_text()
        directories[1] = self.entry2.get_text()
        directories[2] = self.entry3.get_text()



    def close(self,widget,data=None):
        print "Closed"
        gtk.main_quit()


    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

If I execute it, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cutter\cutter.py", line 113, in dir_ch
    directories[1] = self.entry2.get_text()
AttributeError: Base instance has no attribute 'entry2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cutter\cutter.py", line 114, in dir_ch
    directories[2] = self.entry3.get_text()
AttributeError: Base instance has no attribute 'entry3'
```

The funny issue - to my opinion - is that "entry1" is absolutely similar to "entry2" and "entry3" but doesn't make any problems. Do you know why these errors occur?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is the lines:

```
self.entry1.connect("changed",self.dir_ch)
self.entry1.set_text("dir1")
```

Which happens *before* `entry2` or `entry3` is defined, but *after* `entry1` is defined. This causes the `self.dir_ch` callback function to be called. That function then relies on `entry1`, `entry2`, and `entry3` all existing.

One fix would be to define all three fields, with the lines:

```
    self.entry1 = gtk.Entry()
    self.entry2 = gtk.Entry()
    self.entry3 = gtk.Entry()
```

before connecting or changing any of them.

Comment: The traceback isn't particularly helpful (if it's all posted).  At some point it should send you to the line `self.entry1.connect("changed",self.dir_ch)` ...

Comment: You're deadly right... Thank you very much for this fast answer David!